# SQL Server Express Reporting Services is accesible from another server?

Tags: sql-server, ssrs

I am thinking of installing a Sql Server 2017 Express with Advanced Services.
All data will be stored in the local instance as well as the Reporting Services.
The question is if someone in another server could see that reports or only users logged in local server could see them.
Thx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is yes users from another server could see the reports on that server.

[This article shows how to configure SSRS SQL 2017](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/9079/sql-server-reporting-services-ssrs-2017-installation-and-configuration-setup/).  If you look at the article the screenshot for 'Web Service URL' you will see a 'Report Server Web Service URLs'.  When you set up SSRS on the machine this is the URL you would give to users to access the SSRS portal.  This is how they could access the SSRS portal.

Once you have set up and configured the SSRS portal you will need to set up the user accounts to grant access to the SSRS portal.  Configure any firewall access.  Set up data sources, deploy reports etc.